# Trouble creating a batch script to pull lines from an XML file

Tags: xml, batch-file

So I've been trying to write a batch script that will go through an AndroidManifest.xml and pull the permissions used in an app and output it to a .txt file for work instead of having to do it by hand. Part of my job is going in behind the devs and cataloging all the permissions used in the app to make sure they are actually used and not just useless code, so having a list of permissions to just jump to you would make things x100 faster.

For an example, within the xml there are lines that look like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

and I'm trying to add them to an output file as:

```
android.permission.VIBRATE
```

to the .txt file.

Currently, I'm getting the correct number of lines in the output but instead of the permission I'm getting:

```
!line!
```

The code I've written from online examples and tutorials on similar things dealing with XML files is below:

```
ECHO off
REM new line added to fix output below thanks to Compo
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

:start

ECHO Note: Find your list of permissions used in the permissions output file
ECHO Please input the file path to the AndroidManifest you'd like scrapped for permissions 

SET /p manifestpath=
ECHO Verifying inputted path:
ECHO %manifestpath%

CD "%manifestpath%"

(FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-7delims=<=>/ " %%a IN (AndroidManifest.xml) DO (
 IF /i "%%~a%%~b"=="uses-permissionandroid:name" ECHO "%%~c"
)) > permissionsoutput.txt

START permissionsoutput.txt

ECHO to run again enter 'r'
ECHO to exit enter 'e'

SET /p nextaction=
if %nextaction%==r goto :start
if %nextaction%==e :eof
```

UPDATE: Awesome, its actually returning something other then !line! now. But what do I need to do to get it from its current output for permissions from: 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
to something like: 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

UPDATE: Fully working! Posted above code should be fully functional for anyone who needs it as reference for another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `@echo off`, insert a new line

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

It is `delayedexpansion` mode that caused `!var!` to become the *current* value of `var`

---

To retrieve `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from the line posted (please edit the actual line into your original question - comments fight with XML)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q45656376.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-7delims=<=>/ " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF /i "%%~a%%~b"=="uses-permissionandroid:name" ECHO "%%~c"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Where I construct `filename1` for convenience on my system to contain some random  XML including your line.

Read the file, regarding `<=>/` as delimiters; pick the third and remove quotes.

This code is intended to demonstrate how to extract the required data from a file. The first 4 lines simply set the source filename> I use this structure for testing so that I can revise the code easily if there are any problems - and keep all of the data relevant to the question in a related set of files (so *my* batch would in this case be `q45656376.bat` and any related data files are `q45656376.txt`, etc)

The `goto :eof` at the end is superfluous code - a habit I employ to reduce problems with adding subroutines to any batch.

So all that remains is a `for` statement. This statement should be substituted for the `for/f` you already have in your routine. You would then need to change the filename targeted to `"AndroidManifest.xml"` and remove the quotes around the `%%~c` (if you wish) - I used the quotes to visually verify that there were no extra spaces being output.

Note that your `for` statement`is parenthesised`( for ... )>filename`. This is used to redirect the`echo`ed output from the`for`to a file instead of to the console. You'd need to parenthesise the`for` statement in the same manner to produce your output file.

Comment: Awesome, its actually returning something other then !line! now. But what do I need to do to get it from its current output for permissions from:

android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

to something like:

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I'm confused on where I need to insert that code into what I have above, or is it suppose to be its own separate thing?